# error log sqlite failed to load from /cachedGeoposition.db

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, jquery-mobile, error-log

I am developping an app with phonegap and JQM.
I have a problem. Can anyone tell me why I have this error in the log when I launch my app.

```
10-09 13:47:33.316: D/CordovaWebView(26882): >>> loadUrlNow()
10-09 13:47:33.320: D/DroidGap(26882): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
10-09 13:47:33.320: D/DroidGap(26882): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
10-09 13:47:33.363: E/SQLiteLog(26882): (14) cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-09 13:47:33.363: E/SQLiteLog(26882): (14) os_unix.c:30174: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) - 
10-09 13:47:33.371: D/WebKit(26882): ERROR: 
10-09 13:47:33.371: D/WebKit(26882): SQLite database failed to load from /CachedGeoposition.db
10-09 13:47:33.371: D/WebKit(26882): Cause - unable to open database file
10-09 13:47:33.371: D/WebKit(26882): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
10-09 13:47:33.461: D/DroidGap(26882): onMessage(networkconnection,3g)
```

Here is my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="***.mobile"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />    
    <supports-screens 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:resizeable="true" 
android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icone"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  >
    <activity 
        android:name="***.mobile.MainActivity" 
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" > 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 
     <!-- ZXing activities --> 
 <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"  android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"> 
    <intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner.SCAN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter> 
 </activity>

 <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity"  android:label="@string/share_name">
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner.ENCODE"/>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application></manifest>
```

Here is my mainActivity

```
package **.mobile;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.spashscreen);
    //super.init();
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 4000);

 }}
```

Any help would appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to fix it as it is an innocuous log. The WebView component used by PhoneGap tries to load that DB file but it is only actually used by the Android Browser. You are safe to ignore it.

Comment: Could patching PhoneGap like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13181165/3408) silence the error?:

Answer (score 0):

> SQLite database failed to load from /CachedGeoposition.db

Apparently, the database path is missing.

Comment: At the beginning of my app, I did not have this problem. It suddenly appears and I don't know why and how to fix it.